# Get coordinates of a text from an image

Tags: c#, ocr

I am trying to get coordinates of a word from an image of same resolution as my monitor and do some actions on those particular coordinates. I am able to get the coordinates but when I move cursor to same point, it's not where the word is.

I have below method which returns coordinates:

```
protected IronSoftware.Drawing.CropRectangle getCoordinatesOfText(string text)
    {
        var Ocr = new IronTesseract();
        Ocr.Language = OcrLanguage.English;


        using (var ocrInput = new OcrInput(System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(@"..\..\..\Resources\fileImage.jpg")))
        {
            var ocrResult = Ocr.Read(ocrInput);
            int index = -1;
            int counter = 0;
            foreach (var word in ocrResult.Text.Split(" "))
            {

                if (word.Contains(text))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("-" + word + "-");
                    index = counter;
                    return ocrResult.Words[index].Location;
                }
                counter++;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```